# Maintaining a healthy spine when working while traveling?

Tags: health, work

Often when I travel, I have to work long hours: programming

In many cases there is no office chair, resulting in an uncomfortable work position on a regular chair and table, and ultimately in back pain. I am about 190cm or 6'2" tall.

Is there some trick or some pocketable “device” to make my sitting situation better?

Comment: I think this is quite off-topic here - there is no information about traveling - only about ergonomics and health. There are other SE-sites you can post this question.

Comment: @VMAtm: Which SE-site do you recommend? For me it's an issue that I only have when traveling, and that I expect other travelers to have as well.

Comment: @feklee I saw your flag regarding this question being okay according to FAQs as "health and safety related to travel". This is a vague term, but I believe the general understanding is that it would need to be specifically related to the act of travelling. The 'travel' part is an external factor here: sitting ergonomically without an office chair is the main question here. This is why the question was closed and I agree with the community vote.

Comment: @VMAtm: To me the question is about working around limitations of typical workspaces available when traveling, so it is definitely related to traveling! Anyway, I would appreciate if you reply to my earlier question: "Which SE-site do you recommend?" After all, you said: "There are other SE-sites you can post this question." Feel free to move the question.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: Edited the title, as it may have been misleading. What do you think is a more appropriate SE-site for the question?

Comment: @feklee Look who closed the question - there are general users, not moderators. So, if you want to know the community opinion, you should go to the meta, and create a question there. For me, this question is not related to traveling - you have such problem simply while having dinner in Wi-Fi cafe. So I think this is off-topic. Try to commit to the [Health.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health?referrer=IbuXbgN5XEG5LIh8JGLLjA2) - I think this is that you looking for.

Comment: @VNAtm: Is it possible to move the question? Note that I am specifically looking for solutions that work *while traveling*. So if there is some "device" that can make a chair more comfortable, it should be easy to transport, or it should be easily available in many parts of the world. Also note that there are four votes for the reply by sheepeeh - so there is interest in the issue here!

Comment: @feklee I thought at first that with the edit the question would be on-topic because I think I remember seeing an exercise while travelling question but I can't find it. There are some other heath-related questions [similar to this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6536/how-to-prevent-back-pain-after-a-long-day-of-standing) which we have closed for similar reasons. At the moment, [Health.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health) is still in commitment stage. I would suggesting committing to that proposal.

Comment: @feklee So basically: a) can't reopen the question because we've closed similar questions earlier b) cannot migrate, no matching SE site at the moment c) please commit to Health.SE. Thanks for being so understanding and discussing your concerns! Please do hang around in Travel.SE and ask your travel-related questions. :)

Answer (score 4):

Most hotels have "business centers" with office chairs and desks in them, though some of those  do have specific hours. Many major cities also offer temporary workspaces that you can rent for a day.

If the problem is a lack of support, you might try something [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00306FI7Q), which you can attach to whatever chair you're sitting in (I use these in the car). They should be easily packable as you could pack things between the straps and the actual support.

If the trouble is desk height (you're always slouching or bending over to see the screen), then the best you can do is get a lapdesk or build one out of books to add support.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. At the moment I stay in a rented apartment ‒ no hotel with business center (too expensive). I am aware of coworking places, but I prefer to work alone. The support you linked to looks interesting. Perhaps that can be combined with a rotating pillow, also available as accessory for cars. Recently I used a very simple rotating chair, and that was enough to keep my back feel comfortable.